# dynamic UIScrollView with paging and data from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I saw alot of people asking about it, I read everything but still could not figure how to do it. I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled, also I have a NSMutableArray with strings.

what I want to do is that the UIScrollView will show to UITextView with the string and when I change to the next page, it will show the next item on the NSMutableArray.

for some reason I can't get it to work.

```
- (void)setupPage
{
    pagingView.delegate = self;

    [self.pagingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [pagingView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    pagingView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    pagingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    pagingView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    pagingView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    pagingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [pagingView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [pagingView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    for (int i=0;i<[arrCat count];i++)
    {
        UITextView * txtJoke = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
        [pagingView addSubview:txtJoke];

        txtJoke.text = [arrCat objectAtIndex:i];
        txtJoke.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    }
    [pagingView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(960, [pagingView bounds].size.height)];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{
    if (pageControlIsChangingPage) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     *  We switch page at 50% across
     */
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    //pageControl.currentPage = page;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{
    pageControlIsChangingPage = NO;
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender :(int)current
{
    /*
     *  Change the scroll view
     */
    CGRect frame = pagingView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 1;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    [pagingView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

    /*
     *  When the animated scrolling finishings, scrollViewDidEndDecelerating will turn this off
     */
    pageControlIsChangingPage = YES;
}
```

This code is a combination of something from another app that i'm trying to fit into this, but without any success.
Please help. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, all of your UITextView's have the same frame coordinates, so they will be on top of each other. Assuming you're scrolling horizontally, you need to offset the UITextView's x origin by the page width.

Are you using a UIPageControl? If not, you can just deleted the methods other than setupPage. Those other methods are just used for changing the UIPageControl, and changing the page using the UIPageControl.

Here is a basic scroll view implementation similar to yours:

```
static NSUInteger kNumberOfPages = 3;
static NSUInteger kPageWidth = 320;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(kPageWidth * kNumberOfPages, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    self.pageOne.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kPageWidth, self.pageOne.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageOne];

    self.pageTwo.frame = CGRectMake(kPageWidth, 0, kPageWidth, self.pageTwo.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageTwo];

    self.pageThree.frame = CGRectMake(2*kPageWidth, 0, kPageWidth, self.pageThree.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageThree];

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
}

# pragma mark - Scroll View Related Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    // We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in
    // which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from
    // the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.
    if (pageControlUsed_)
    {
        // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging
        return;
    }

    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - kPageWidth / 2) / kPageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}

// At the begin of scroll dragging, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    pageControlUsed_ = NO;
} 

// At the end of scroll animation, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    pageControlUsed_ = NO; 
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender
{ 
    int page = self.pageControl.currentPage;

// update the scroll view to the appropriate page
    CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

// Set the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl. See scrollViewDidScroll: above.
    pageControlUsed_ = YES;
}
```

Comment: That makes it pretty easy, just offset the frames of your UITextViews and it should work.

Comment: Is it possible to use paging without PageControl? yeah right?

Comment: Yes, you do not need a page control to have paging in the scroll view. Also I notice you're not explicitly setting the frame of your scroll view, presumably the width is 320?

Comment: I dont want to define the pages like this, I have NSMutableArray with lets say 10 objects, I want to load the text inside of each item to each page in the UIScrollView, I want it to be dynamically.

Comment: That's fine. In the setupPage method just offset the x origin of each UITextView by (i*pageWidth), and redefine the scroll view content size to be (numberOfPages*pageWidth). Where numberOfPages is the number of items in your array obviously.

Comment: is it smart to create a for loop that will create UIScrollView with a subview of UIView by the numbers of items in NSMutableArray? if it will be 100 items in the array or even more, it will not take long time to load?

Comment: If you have that many, it might be better to add only the views you need: the one on the page you are currently looking at, the one on the page before, and the one on the page after. When you scroll, use the - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender to check if the page has changed, and add and remove views from the scroll view.

Comment: after 2-3 hours of trying, can't do that.. don't know how.